# Loading node with nodelet manager doesn't work

Tags: ros, nodelet, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I work in simulation.

I have this node in the launch file:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="turtlebot_follower"
      args="standalone turtlebot_follower/TurtlebotFollower">
      <remap from="depth/points" to="camera/depth/points"/>
</node>
```

The program works. "turtlebot_follower" node subscribes to /camera/depth/points. Then I want to load this node in nodelet_manager. Here is a new launch file:

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="turtlebot_follower"
      args="load turtlebot_follower/TurtlebotFollower manager">
      <remap from="depth/points" to="camera/depth/points"/>
</node>
```

I launched manager:

```
 rosrun nodelet nodelet manager
```

Then I run launch file. The program doesn't work. There is no subscriber to /camera/depth/points topic.

How can I solve this problem?

UPDATE: using command

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet manager
```

instead of

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=nodelet_manager
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226114/loading-node-with-nodelet-manager-doesn%27t-work/) by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used difference namespace. When I launched nodelet manager in the same namespace it worked.

---

Originally posted by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) with karma: 77 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0